# Why I get only first element?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I'm parsing [this page](https://www.oddsportal.com/profile/spongebobga1/my-predictions/results/)

I pull out links from the `number2 classes`. Further in the loop I go through each element of `number2` and try to get the results from the class `'center bold table-odds'`. To do this, I try to find the `parents` of each link, but the problem is that every time I get the result from the `first element` (in this example it is *31:25*)

```
<table class="table-main odds prediction-table" id="prediction-table-1">
    <tbody>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td rowspan="3" class="center status-text-won">W</td>
            <td rowspan="3" id="status-IwnElQet" class="table-time center datet t1570978800-6-1-0-0 ">Today<br>15:00</td>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" class="table-participant">
                <a class="number2" href="/handball/europe/challenge-cup/vogosca-sviesa-IwnElQet/#1X2;2">1X2</a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3" class="center bold table-odds">31:25</td>
            <td class="center table-odds result-ok"><a href="">1.50</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
            <td rowspan="3" class="center status-text-lost">L</td>
            <td rowspan="3" id="status-0IZCD4u8" class="table-time center datet t1570978800-6-1-0-0 ">Today<br>15:00</td>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2" class="table-participant">
                <a class="number2" href="/volleyball/italy/serie-a2-women/marignano-talmassons-0IZCD4u8/#ah;2;-14.50;3">AH -14.5 Points</a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3" class="center bold table-odds">3:1</td>
            <td class="center table-odds result-ok"><a href="">2.01</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
odds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('number2')

for odd in odds:   
     print(odd.get_attribute('href')) 
     print(odd.find_element_by_xpath('../..').find_element_by_class_name('center bold table-odds').text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to do it:

```
odds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('number2')

for odd in odds:   
    print(odd.get_attribute('href')) 
    print(odd.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::tr[1]').find_element_by_css_selector('.center.bold.table-odds').text)
    # or 
    # print(odd.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::tr[1]//td[4]')
    # or 
    # print(odd.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::tr[1]//td[contains(@class,'bold')]')
```

Second way:

```
rows = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#prediction-table-1 > tbody > tr')
for row in rows:   
    print(row.find_element_by_css_selector('.number2').get_attribute('href')) 
    print(row.find_element_by_css_selector('.center.bold.table-odds').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
find_element_by_class_name
```

should be

```
find_elements_by_class_name
```

Make it plural to get them all. [Read more here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: It's not a typo. I do not need everything. I need to iterate separately, one for each element of `number2`

Comment: If you run as find_elements_by_class_name a list is returned and you can get each item as you need them using [0]

Comment: You did not understand the essence of my question. I get all the elements with the class `number2`. Next, I need to get the result through the `parent` of each such element (an element with the class `center bold ...`). I get the `parent`, but when I get the `result`, I constantly get the result from the `first element`. Try to reproduce my situation. I attached the link. It is necessary to observe just such logic as I described (because there are not so unambiguous situations)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one class with name "number2" you are getting only on element and your is iterating once only.
odds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('number2')

Comment: There is a 15 elements with class name "number2".